# How can I use the $ symbol?

Tags: command-line

I know there are probably a lot of forums on this symbol specifically, but I want to know how I can use $ in calls. I know how to do

```
echo $USER
```

but how could I expand my knowledge of this symbol, if I wanted to run something like nmap with finding the subnet or if I wanted to make a file because these don't work:

```
 mkdir $IP
 mkdir $gateway

 nmap $ip
 nmap $subnetwork
```

Can you set some examples on how to use this symbol to make files or pull information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### General

The basic use of $ as in `$USER` is to tell the shell, that you talking about a shell variable.

See **`man bash`** and scroll to (or jump to)

- `Special Parameters`
- `EXPANSION`
- `Parameter Expansion`

But it might be a bit difficult to digest the descriptions in `man bash`. You might find it easier to read some **tutorial**, that you can find via the internet, for example

- [Variables! Temporary stores of information](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-variables.php)
- [The bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams#mass_usage)

### Examples

The shell variable must be defined (either generally in the shell or specifically by you). For example `USER` is a general variable, but `subnet` is not defined in my computer, so I would have to declare it,

```
subnet="some-text-or-number-string"
```

Then it can be viewed by

```
echo "$subnet"
```

and used in other commands (like you want to use it).

`IP` is not defined in my computer, but standard variables use upper case, so it is a good idea to use lower case for your own variables to avoid conflicts.

```
ip=192.168.0.2
```

You can check it with

```
echo "$ip"
```

and remove it with

```
unset ip
```

---

Adding examples according to tips from @Terrance and @Jo-ErlendSchinstad

The command you are looking for with `nmap` can be done with `ip route` like so:

```
nmap -sP $(ip route | grep kernel | awk '{print $1}')
```

where **`$(a command line)`** lets you use the [standard] **output** of a command line in the shell context, explained with the following simpler example,

```
myusername=$(whoami)
```

Which can be viewed by

```
echo $myusername
```

---

A simple calculator for integers is created with double parentheses like so,

```
$ echo $((1+2))
3

$ r=5
$ area=$((r**2 * 314 / 100))
$ echo "the circle's area is approx. = $area"
the circle's area is approx. = 78
```

Comment: ok, but how would i do an nmap without the numerical value, if i wanted to do something like nmap $subnet

Comment: The shell variable must be defined (either generally in the shell or specifically by you). For example `USER` is a general variable, but `subnet` is not defined in my computer, so I would have to declare it: `subnet="some-text-or-number-string"`. Then it can be viewed by `echo "$subnet"` and used in other commands (like you want to use it).

Comment: so there's no way to work around that with something like this nmap -exec ip addr show eth0 | grep "inet\b" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1

Comment: In linux there are [almost] always ways to work around things ;-) Please tell us exactly what you want to do, and it will be easier to help. - (please note that I know a bit about shell variables, but not much about networking.)

Comment: i just ran subnet="192.168.1.0/24"; nmap $subnet thank you for your time

Comment: @hellomoto, You are welcome, I'm glad I could help :-)

Comment: @hellomoto The command you are looking for with nmap can be done with `ip route` like so:  `nmap -sP $(ip route | grep kernel | awk '{print $1}')`

Comment: Or something simpler, like myusername = $(whoami)

Comment: When you see backticks used for commands in documentation you can use $ to replace them. ie ` uname -r ` can be replaced with `$(uname -r)`. From the command line and in scripts you can see program name using `$0`.